# llvm-opt fails to load a simple pass

Tags: llvm

I have installed the latest LLVM svn trunk using cmake (this is the first time I have used cmake to build LLVM).

The problem is that when I try to make the Hello pass from the LLVM tutorial, it compiles fine (a .so file is created), but the opt tool is unable to load it. It fails with the following message

$ opt -load ./Hello/libLLVMHello2.so
  Error opening './Hello/libLLVMHello2.so': ./Hello/libLLVMHello2.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN4llvm12FunctionPassE
  -load request ignored.

I am using cmake, and following the instructions at http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#cmake-out-of-source-pass

I have some other passes lying around, but I do not want to use the cmake build system until this problem is solved.

Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You built your Hello pass with rtti enabled, while LLVM is built without.